# Unbold qcounter or enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, bold

I want to ask about my work...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{qcounter}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}
{\bfseries{}\textnormal{Langkah \arabic{qcounter}~}}
{
\usecounter{qcounter}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1in}
\bfseries
\setlength\labelwidth{3in}
}
\item \textnormal{a}
\item \textnormal{b}
\item \textnormal{c}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textnormal{q}
\item \textnormal{w}
\item \textnormal{e}
\item \textnormal{r}
\end{enumerate}
\item \textnormal{c}
\item \textnormal{d}
\item \textnormal{f}
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

I want that `enumerate` (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) unbold. But I can't change it. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Removing the first `\bfseries{}` from your code removes the bold font on these labels.  Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to locally set your list requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1in,labelwidth=3in,label=\textnormal{Langkah~\arabic*~}]
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item q
    \item w
    \item e
    \item r
  \end{enumerate}
  \item c
  \item d
  \item f
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thxxxx...its work

Comment: @uyas don't forget to upvote Werner's answer. If it has resolved the issue (which it sounds like it has), please click on the green check mark- this gives Werner some well-earned reputation points for his code :) Welcome to the group!